# Socket programming/sending a binary image data over wireless

Tags: c#, sockets

How can I send an array of bytes (`byte[]`) over wireless?

I am currently working on a client/server chat application. I have implemented various other features e.g profile management but the problem I'm facing is trying to send an image over wireless.

I already know how to convert an image into byte format and saving/retrieving from a database, but when it comes to sending it in TCP/IP it doesn't work with the class am using (`StreamWriter`).

What classes do I need to send the byte stream? Without interfering with his profile details?

(in my chat register form)
This is my algorithm: concatenate user information e.g his username, password, location, gender, status and embed server symbols e.g(%,^,~,`) so the server can break his information apart and save it in the data base.

Everything was working just fine until I tried concatenating the byte array (`byte[]` i.e image data), with his information.

My solution: I will send his information separately i.e all strings will be together and his image will stand alone when I want to send his profile details to the server.

My classes:am using stream Writer to write user information to the server.
please show me an example using a good class e.g (binary writer) to send his profile picture. If I can get the binary code on the server I would really appreciate it, thanks a lot.

Comment: `StreamWriter` is suitable for writing strings. Use `BinaryWriter` to write binary data.

Answer (score 2):

`TcpClient` will work.

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect(server, port);
Stream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

byte[] testString = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test");
stream.Write(testString, 0, testString.Length);

stream.Close();
tcpClient.Close();
```

That will send the `string` "test".  You can apply the same logic to different data formats.

```
byte[] hexMsg = new byte[] { 0x1A, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
stream.Write(hexMsg, 0, hexMsg.Length);
```

That will send some `hex` values across the stream.

Comment: Thanks for your help all i'm grateful,i made an algorithm to solve it due to my impatience and lack of experience using bainary writer.i used a loop to convert each bytes in the image(byte[])to string and insert a breaking symbol after each(comma sign),then i sent it with stream writer,i had something like (imageData.length,244,56,0,0,78,12) on the server side with the comma's emmbeded,with dat i cud reinsert the strings before each comma,convert it back to byte and push(insert into the next index) it in a new byte array and decode the color information.